# How to get the minimum value of an instance of django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get the minimum or the lowest value of a model field in django model. The field is `room_Price`. I am therefore trying to get the minimum of value of this field for each instance of a model. My model are as as follows

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    property_photo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='hotel_photos')
    star_rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

```
class Room(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels,on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    room_photo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='room_photos')
    room_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    room_details = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    room_Capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    # guest_numbers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    room_Price= models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    total_Rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

**More details**
From the above models, a hotel can have as many rooms as possible. Now i want to fetch the lowest priced room for each hotel. I tried to use `Hotels.objects.aggregate(min_price=Min('room__room_Price'))` but it is fetching the overall minimum price of all the hotel rooms. Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `ordering` to your model and then find lowest price in a loop:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['room_Price']
```

And filter in views:

```
lowest_prices = {}
for i in Hotels.objects.all():
    price = Room.objects.filter(hotel=i.id)[0].room_Price
    lowest_prices[i.name] = price
print(lowest_prices)
```

I put prices in a dict, but you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was beautiful. It worked out like a charm!. Problem solved.

Comment: Just one more quick question how can i run the same code but with  `OneToOneField` foreignkey. I am getting empty set when i do the same on the  'OneToOneField' field

Comment: @Paul I don't understand how do you want to find lowest if there's only one related object?

Comment: Oops sorry about that. I have was actually wrong. The field i am working with is not OneToMany field. I was encountering **IndexError: list index out of range** error on some models so  i had to add `if Hotels.objects.filter(hotel=i.id).exists():` to check if object exist. Now it's all working good